# SQL query to allow for latest datasets per items

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, conditional-statements

I have this table in an SQL server database:

[image: Table]

and I would like a query that gives me the values of cw1, cw2,cw3 for a restricted date condition.

I would like a query giving me the "latest" values of cw1, cw2, cw3 giving me previous values of cw1, cw2, cw3, if they are null for the last plan_date. This would be with a date condition.

So if the condition is **plan_date between "02.01.2020" and "04.01.2020"** then the result should be

> 1 04.01.2020 null, 9, 4
>
> 2 03.01.2020 30 , 15, 2

where, for example, the "30" is from the last previous date for item_nr 2.

Comment: Hi, welcome on stackoverflow. Please provide https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, it will speed up helping you.

Comment: Generally what you need is to use window functions for that. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the last value using `first_value()`.  Unfortunately, that is a window function, but `select` distinct solves that:

```
select distinct item_nr,
       first_value(cw1) over (partition by item_nr
                              order by (case when cw1 is not null then 1 else 2 end), plan_date desc
                             ) as imputed_cw1,
       first_value(cw2) over (partition by item_nr
                              order by (case when cw2 is not null then 1 else 2 end), plan_date desc
                             ) as imputed_cw2,
       first_value(cw3) over (partition by item_nr
                              order by (case when cw3 is not null then 1 else 2 end), plan_date desc
                             ) as imputed_cw3
from t;
```

You can add a `where` clause after the `from`.

The `first_value()` window function returns the first value from each partition.  The partition is ordered to put the non-`NULL` values first, and then order by time descending.  So, the most recent non-`NULL` value is first.

The only downside is that it is a window function, so the `select distinct` is needed to get the most recent value for each `item_nr`.

Comment: thanks a lot. That works great. The only thing is that the cw's are 52 in number, so I'll have quite  a few rows of code, but most importantly it works:)

Comment: I am indeed using a "where" clause after the "from" to narrow the plan_date. How would I store it as a view so that I can still use the where clause?

Comment: @KingsleyObeng . . . I think you should ask another question to be very clear on what you are looking for.